# db-driven / programmatic validation asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I want to create a system where users can create forms through a UI, and the list of fields gets stored in in the database. The user can then choose validations for the form, and those get stored in the datbase too. When a user visits the form, the correct fields are displayed, and when they submit the form the correct validations are pulled from the db and run against the submitted data. Is there already any kind of system that does this (ideally open source).

I know there are form and survey services out there but I don't want a SaaS solution because I need to be able to customize most aspects (front end, server side, and db).

Answer (score 0):

Type "open source survey software" into a search engine, and you'll find [LimeSurvey](http://www.limesurvey.org/), an active project with a viable survey system that you can manage and customize on your own server. It supports a number of common SQL implementations.

It's not aligned with the specific language & environment tags in your question, but otherwise seems a fit.